# Android push notification comes up then instantly gets dismissed automatically

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm getting push notifications that get displayed then instantly get dismissed automatically.  Im wanting to it so the user must manually dismiss it or click on it to go to the app.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private void sendNotification(Bundle msg, final int notID) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        myintent.putExtras(msg);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setTicker(myintent.getStringExtra("ticker"));
        mBuilder.setContentText(myintent.getStringExtra("contentText"));
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(myintent.getStringExtra("contentTitle"));
        mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: can you post your code you are using to show notification??

Comment: added sendNotification method code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code. Just small difference in PendingIntent and setAutoCancel.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class), 0);
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setSound(customSoundURI).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(msg);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Comment: Welcome  :) Its my first answer ;) :P